# What will be the output if I connect two 1.5 AA Alkaline batteries (3V) to a 3.3V Voltage regulator (LM1117)?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

What will be the output if I connect two 1.5 AA Alkaline batteries (3V) to a 3.3V Voltage regulator (LM1117)?

Will it give me 3.3V output? If yes... what extra components (Capacitors/Resistors) should I connect? A circuit diagram will be highly helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LM1117 is a Linenar regulator, this mean, Vin > Vout in any case. You can not "increase" the voltage. If you want to do so, you better use a boost regulator. But I'm not sure it will work for a such little amount extra voltage (I can be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume you have a load of only a few mA, say an LED. Lets also assume your batteries are brand new giving them a terminal voltage of approximately 1.7V, or with two in series 3.4V.

Referring to the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf), we can see that under the load condition I assumed (<100mA), the dropout voltage of the regulator will be approximately 1.1V. This means that regulator will drop at least this much voltage.

If you supply a 3.4V input to the regulator, you will actually get 2.3V out because the regulator is dropping the input voltage by at **least** 1.1V.

Once the batteries run down a small amount to a nominal 1.5V terminal voltage, or 3V for two in series, the output will now be 1.9V because again the regulator has a minimum voltage drop due to its internal circuitry.

---

It is a common misconception that a linear voltage regulator that has a rated 3.3V output will output that no matter what, however this is not the case. The way a linear regulator works is to simply adjust its resistance using a transistor to drop enough voltage under the current load conditions to reduce the input voltage down to the required output voltage. Incidentally this is why they get very hot when the input voltage is much higher than the output and/or a large current is being drawn.

This type of regulator cannot **increase** the voltage, it can only **decrease** it. In order to boost the voltage to a higher output that input, you need to use a switching regulator (e.g. boost topology) or charge pump. These use typically either an inductor (switching regulator) or a capacitor (charge pump) being switched at high speed to achieve a voltage increase.

Answer (score -2):

< Will it give me 3.3V output?

no. it will produce 3v and with no ability to take on any meaningful load. if you want, try for yourself.

Comment: It won't even produce 3v, there is always a voltage drop in linear regulator

Comment: > there is always a voltage drop in linear regulator. not if there is no load.

Comment: If you take a look at figure 1 p9 in the LM1117 datasheet (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) there is always a voltage drop, even if there is no load